# How to assign values from one array to others when there are too many?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I clearly didn't know how to explain myself in the title..
I have an array with information from a survey, the array is giving me the apps people say they use more and how they evaluated them.
From a list where you can choose the following apps:

- Word
- Excel
- Power Point
- Access
- Power Bi

You must rate each app by the following aspects:

- Usability
- Performance
- Mobile capability
- Data movement

These functions can be evaluated as "1-Poor", "2-Average", "3-Good" or "4-N/A".

Also each person is divided by their continent: America, Asia, Europe, Africa, Oceania.

**My Problem:**
I need to separate people by their continent.
And by how they evaluated each of the apps:

People from **America** who rated as "Poor" **Word** in "Usability".
People from **America** who rated as "Poor" **Word** in "Performance".
People from **America** who rated as "Poor" **Word** in "Mobile capability".
People from **America** who rated as "Poor" **Word** in "Data movement".

I need to do this exact loop for each evaluation: poor, average, good and N/A.
And also for each app: Word, Excel, Power Point, Access, Power Bi.
And also by Continent: America, Asia, Europe, Africa, Oceania.

This is how my array looks (just an example of one person):

```
var results = [
{
    "Author": "Person 1",
    "Word Usability": "3",
    "Word Performance": "2",
    "Word Mobile capability": "1",
    "Word Data movement": "4",
    "Excel Usability": "3",
    "Excel Performance": "2",
    "Excel Mobile capability": "1",
    "Excel Data movement": "4",
    "PowerPoint Usability": "3",
    "PowerPoint Performance": "2",
    "PowerPoint Mobile capability": "1",
    "PowerPoint Data movement": "4",
    "Access Usability": "3",
    "Access Performance": "2",
    "Access Mobile capability": "1",
    "Access Data movement": "4",
    "PowerBi Usability": "3",
    "PowerBi Performance": "2",
    "PowerBi Mobile capability": "1",
    "PowerBi Data movement": "4",
    "Continent": "America"
},
...
]
```

What I did was to create various arrays and then looped them to separate people by Region, and by how they evaluated each app by each of the aspects marked before:

```
<script>
//I created arrays for each continent
var america = [],
    europe = [],
    asia = [],
    africa = [],
    oceania = [];

//And also separate the count of each "evaluation" from each aspect to rate the app
var americaWord_Usability1 = 0,
    americaWord_Usability2 = 0,
    americaWord_Usability3 = 0,
    americaWord_Usability4 = 0;
var americaWord_Performance1 = 0,
    americaWord_Performance2 = 0,
    americaWord_Performance3 = 0,
    americaWord_Performance4 = 0;
...

//I make the loop
for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
    var currentItem = results[i];

    //depending their continent, I send each people to their correspondent array
    if(currentItem.Continent == "America") {
        america.push(currentItem);
    }
    ...
}

//now I loop by region and send them depending their app and how they were evaluated in each aspect
for(var q=0;q<america.length;q++){
    var currentItem = america[q];

    if(currentItem["Word Usability"] == "1") {
        americaWord_Usability1++;
    } else if(currentItem["Word Usability"] == "2") {
        americaWord_Usability2++;
    } else if(currentItem["Word Usability"] == "3") {
        americaWord_Usability3++;
    } else {
        americaWord_Usability4++;
    }
    if(currentItem["Word Performance"] == "1") {
        americaWord_Performance1++;
    } else if(currentItem["Word Performance"] == "2") {
        americaWord_Performance2++;
    } else if(currentItem["Word Performance"] == "3") {
        americaWord_Performance3++;
    } else {
        americaWord_Performance4++;
    }
    ...
}
</script>
```

With this method it all becomes a nightmare. It is a lot of code because I need to make an array for each continent and an array for each aspect to rate of each app!
My actual code is a little bit longer, there are much more aspects to rate and more apps. So my code became horribly long.

My question here is: **Is there a better and easier way to achieve this?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things easier, you could just create the arrays on the fly:

```
var userData = [];

for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
    var currentItem = results[i];

    // If the subarray doesn't exist yet, create it
    if (userData[currentItem.Continent] == null) userData[currentItem.Continent] = [];

    // Push the data into the corresponding array
    userData[currentItem.Continent].push(currentItem);
}
```

Now you will have an array that has all the users separated by continent. You can apply the same logic to going through your ratings, so for example:

```
// List all the possible keywords for ratings here
var ratingKeywords = ["Word Usability", "Excel Usability"];

// Empty arra for ratings
var ratings = [];

// Go through the continents
for (var continentName in userData) {
    var continent = userData[continentName];
    // Array for continent ratings

    if (!ratings[continentName]) ratings[continentName] = []; 

    for (var u in continent) {
        var user = continent[u];
        for (var k in ratingKeywords) {
            var keyword = ratingKeywords[k];
            console.log(keyword);

            var rating = user[keyword];

            if (!ratings[continentName][keyword]) ratings[continentName][keyword] = [];
            if (!ratings[continentName][keyword][rating.toString()]) ratings[continentName][keyword][rating.toString()] = 0;
            ratings[continentName][keyword][rating.toString()]++;
        }
    }
}
```

This looks a bit clunky, but you won't need to hard-code anything. And if a new continent emerges (which probably won't happen because of the rising sea levels, please go vegan or reduce your meat consumption as soon as possible), this code should still work.

You will end up with an array that has the following structure, for example:
`ratings["Europe"]["Word Usability"][5]: 400`

*(Note that you maybe shouldn't use for-in-loops, but... yeah)*

Comment: Two questions. 1: In the **ratingKeywords** array, must I add ALL aspects of each app or only the ones for _"usability"_? 2: I think there is a problem with the part of `keyword` (not very sure), it is throwing this error: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` in the part of `if (!ratings[region][keyword][rating])`

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I was distracted when finishing my answer and didn't really look at the original data, so I edited it. It should work now. The ratingKeywords here are anything you want to track, so yes, in this example you should add everything. You could also create keyword array dynamically. (Such as `let keyword = app + " " + property;`)

Comment: Wow, now works better, thanks for your help in this :) ..only a little problem: when there are no items in a certain aspect of a certain app and continent it throws the value as `undefined`, for example: `console.log(ratings["America"]["Word Performance"][1])` gives me **undefined** because there are no values in the "America" array with "Word Performance: 1" ...how can I make it throw "0" (zero) instead?

Comment: You could init the score arrays with zeroes as default value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript filters instead. like following

```
ex:
   filteredListwith1 = results.filter((item) => { 
         if(item.continent === 'America' && item['Word Usability'] === '1') {
              return item;
          });
    americaBox_Usability1 = filteredListwith1.length;
```

same thing you can repeat for 2 and 3 as well.

Comment: Don't know if this actually reduces the code... I mean, would I have to write this block of code for each of the apps, each aspect to rate, and each number (1, 2, 3, and 4)? Because then I think my `if` statement inside the loop is actually shorter.